# Getting number of days in a month

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a comboBox with all of the months in it.

What I need to know is the number of days in the chosen month.

```
var month = cmbMonth.SelectedIndex + 1;
DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(month);
```

So if a user selects January, I need to save 31 to a variable.

Answer (score 390, accepted):

You want [`DateTime.DaysInMonth`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.daysinmonth.aspx):

```
int days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);
```

Obviously it varies by year, as sometimes February has 28 days and sometimes 29. You could always pick a particular year (leap or not) if you want to "fix" it to one value or other.

Answer (score 35):

Use [System.DateTime.DaysInMonth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.daysinmonth.aspx), from code sample:

```
const int July = 7;
const int Feb = 2;

// daysInJuly gets 31.
int daysInJuly = System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(2001, July);

// daysInFeb gets 28 because the year 1998 was not a leap year.
int daysInFeb = System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(1998, Feb);

// daysInFebLeap gets 29 because the year 1996 was a leap year.
int daysInFebLeap = System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(1996, Feb);
```

Answer (score 17):

To find the number of days in a month, **DateTime** class provides a method **"DaysInMonth(int year, int month)".**
This method returns the total number of days in a specified month.

```
public int TotalNumberOfDaysInMonth(int year, int month)
    {
        return DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);
    }
```

**OR**

```
int days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(2018,05);
```

Output :- 31

Answer (score 3):

```
  int month = Convert.ToInt32(ddlMonth.SelectedValue);/*Store month Value From page*/
  int year = Convert.ToInt32(txtYear.Value);/*Store Year Value From page*/
  int days = System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month); /*this will store no. of days for month, year that we store*/
```

Answer (score 2):

I made it calculate days in month from datetimepicker selected month and year , and I but the code in datetimepicker1 textchanged to return the result in a textbox
with this code

```
private void DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int s = System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTimePicker1.Value.Date.Year, DateTimePicker1.Value.Date.Month);

    TextBox1.Text = s.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 int days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(int year,int month);
```

or

```
 int days=System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetDaysInMonth(int year,int month);
```

you have to pass year and month as `int` then days in month will be return on currespoting year and month

Answer (score 0):

For those who need the days in month to set a new date...

I have a situation where I need to convert a supplied date to the last day of the supplied dates month, then formatted to a string.  If it fails, returns "N/A"

```
string dueDate = "N/A";
if (DateTime.TryParse(doneDate, out DateTime dateSupplied))
{
    dueDate = new DateTime(
        dateSupplied.Year, 
        dateSupplied.Month, 
        DateTime.DaysInMonth(
            dateSupplied.Year, 
            dateSupplied.Month)
     ).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
} 
return dueDate;
```

Answer (score -1):

- `int days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month);`

---

if you want to find days in this year and present month then this is best

Answer (score -1):

You can use the for loop to get a specific year by doing a subtraction or addition in DateTime.Now.Year, then you can have another loop for 12 standard months for each year. Inside these for loops, you can use [DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);](https://c-sharptutorial.com/csharparticles/how-to-get-number-of-days-in-month-using-in-csharp) method for getting the number of days in a month.

For loop is very beneficial in terms of speed and performance whenever you need to get days in months for a large number of years. For example, if you have the need to get days and months from the previous 50 years of the current year and you want to iterate it for the next 50 years, then a for loop is very beneficial in terms of speed and performance.

```
using System;
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int year = DateTime.Now.Year; year <= DateTime.Now.Year + 1; year++)
        {
            for (int month = 1; month <= 12; month++)
            {
                int daysinMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);
                for (int Day = 1; Day <= daysinMonth; Day++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The Day Of Month is = {0}", Day);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?