# Getting number of days for a specific month

Tags: c#, datetime

how could i programmatically detect, how many days are there for a particular month & year.

Comment: Do you need to take advantage of C# or you want the general algorithm?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting number of days in a month](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832468/getting-number-of-days-in-a-month)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

It's [already there](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.daysinmonth.aspx):

```
DateTime.DaysInMonth(int year, int month);
```

should do it.

Comment: Nice! one never stops discovering cute little corners of the .NET Framework.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this should do what you want:

```
static int GetDaysInMonth(int year, int month) {
    DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(year, month, 1);
    DateTime dt2 = dt1.AddMonths(1);
    TimeSpan ts = dt2 - dt1;
    return (int)ts.TotalDays;
}
```

You get the first day of the month, add one month and count the days in between.

Comment: Why would he used such a horrible method when it already exists and which in theory could be modified to support any calendar.

Comment: @Ramhound: When @Paolo answered he probably didn't know the method already existed.

Comment: Yes, I just didn't know the method existed :)