# Generate random date and time in a service

Tags: c#, wcf, random, service, datetimepicker

I'm trying to have a kind of method that is in a service that can be accessed by a form so that I can use this method to generate a random date in a date time picker. It just doesn't work however, I have two DTP's called dtp_Current and dtp_New

This is accessed on a form and I have two buttons that say before and after, when before is clicked you are guessing the newly generated date will be before the current date and if you click after it's guessing it's gonna be after the currently generated date. I have to do this using a service however

public int RandomDate()

is what i'd like the method to be called in the Service, how would I go about doing this so when the after button is clicked it checks dtp_Current date to see if dtp_New is larger

I hope this makes sense

summary:
have a form and a service reference
need service reference to generate a random date in dtp_Current
then when before or after is clicked generate a new date in dtp_New 
then to check if dtp_New is larger or smaller than dtp_Current

Comment: Unfortunately, your question only makes partly sense; perhaps it would be more clear if you could add some code to show what exactly the problem is? How far have you come in you task? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Not very far if I'm honest. I have a form like said but it also has a service reference. I need the datetime to be generated in the service at the start but i'm not sure how I'd go about generating a new date in a datetime picker

Comment: I added a summary which I think makes it more clear

Comment: It's still not quite clear what the problem is; are you getting a date from the service? Do you need to change the service to return a random date? Or to do comparisons between dates? The relationship between the service and your client is unclear. Is it a webform? (are you able to access the service at all, or is that a part of the problem?)

Comment: It's just practice using Services. It's a WCFService and all I need it to do is for the client to contact the service for a new date. Once I actually figure out how to generate a date from the service and get it to change the datetimepicker on the form I think I'll be able to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me like the main problem here is simply to create a method that generates a random date.

One way to do this and retain a certain level of control over which dates you get, is to just generate random numbers for date, month and year. For year, you could do:

```
Random r = new Random();

int randomYear = r.Next(1990, 2015); // random year between 1990 and 2014    
int randomMonthNr = r.Next(1,13);
int maxDayNr = DateTime.DaysInMonth(randomYear, randomMonthNr);
int randomDayNr = r.Next(1, (maxDayNr + 1));
```

Do something similar for date and month, and just use that in:

```
var randomDate = new DateTime(randomYear, randomMonthNr, randomDayNr);
```

(Note: Generate the month first, then [find out the number of days in the resulting month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832468/getting-number-of-days-in-a-month), and use that as the upper limit when generating a number for the date, so you get a max of 28 or 29 for February, etc).

Once the date(s) are created, you can simply compare them using `<=` and `>=` (with or without the `=`). If you need to compare them within the context of the service, just send a `DateTime` as a parameter to the service, and compare it there.

---

**Update: Connecting to the service**

Open the folder under your Visual Studio project for the client. Right click the service reference, and select `View in Object Browser`. There, you should see a hierarchy of the types and namespaces from your service. Look for a type called something like `YourServiceNameClient`. This will be an automatically generated type that you can use to connect to your service (`Client` will just be appended to the type that the service reference has identified).

Use it like:

```
var yourServiceReference = new YourServiceNameClient();
var yourGeneratedDate = yourServiceReference.GetNewRandomDate();
```

This obviously assumes `GetNewRandomDate()` is a method you have exposed in your service. Hope this is helpful...

Comment: Sorry, I feel so dense for not understanding this. Would this go in the Service? I'm not sure what .Dump does either and I need it to generate a random number in an existing DTP and not a new one. Sorry for being so useless with this D:

Comment: Oops, appologies - the `Dump()` was not supposed to be in there. All this code does is generate a random int for the year, in the range 1990 to 2014. My point was that you could just do the same for month and date - ie. genaret three random numbers for the three "parts" of the date, and that way be able to control and fine-tune what dates are created in a simple way. You should place that code wherever you need to generate your random date.

Comment: Updated my answer for a little more clarity.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've got the generating to work. How would I store the random date so that I can compare a newly generated date to see if it was larger or smaller than the other one?

Comment: The easiest way is to store them on the client side somehow, and just do the comparisons there. You could store them on the server side too, by storing them in a DB or something, or possibly using a WCF session, but that would be more complex. Also, since you could in theory have several clients using the same service, keeping the dates for each individual client in the client itself seems to make more sense to me. :)

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, trying to keep it simple hah! I don't have much of an idea how I'd store the value so it can be compared to the other. txt_Date.Text = client.RandomDate().ToString(); is the output I have, what would you suggest? (sorry for asking so many questions)

Comment: Depends on your context (a website? Perhaps a session variable, or a hidden field stored in the ViewState?). Anyway, this is a little beyond the scope of your original question..

Comment: Yeah I've got it done now anyway, thanks for your help man :)

Answer (score 2):

To Generate the random date here is the c# code:

```
 DateTime RandomDay()
    {
        DateTime start = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1);
        Random gen = new Random();

        int range = (DateTime.Today - start).Days;           
        return start.AddDays(gen.Next(range));
    }
```

Comment: I tried this but I already have two dtp's named dtp_Current and dtp_New on a windows form and I need the date to be generated on those and not new ones.

Comment: i think you should share your code for better understanding of question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `random.Next` using time in milliseconds.