# How to get the days of the next month?

Tags: c#, datetime, daycount

*What I'm trying to achieve*

I'm trying to get the number of days of two months (the current) and the next month. Actually I succesfully achieve this, using that code:

```
int monthDays = DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month);
string[] days = Enumerable.Range(1, monthDays).Select(x => x.ToString("D2")).ToArray();
```

essentially I used the function `DaysInMonth` and then I generated a `List<int>` that represents the days of that month.

*Problem*

Now, I want get also the days of the next month, but I've some problem to handle the following situation:

```
December 2018 (current)
January 2019 (next)
```

*What I tried*

as you can see the `year` has changed, so the code that I wrote for get the days of next months will fail:

```
var nextMonth = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1).AddMonths(1);
monthDays = DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.Year, nextMonth.Month);
days = Enumerable.Range(1, monthDays).Select(x => x.ToString("D2")).ToArray();
```

how can I manage the new year in the `next` month?

Comment: You know how you're accessing `nextMonth.Month` to obtain *its* month rather than using `DateTime.Now`? Why aren't you doing the same for `Year`?

Comment: As an aside, it's **january** :)

Comment: as @Damien_The_Unbeliever suggested, use `monthDays = DateTime.DaysInMonth(nextMonth.Year, nextMonth.Month);`

Comment: what is your definition of "the days in the month"? Like Mon, Tues... or 1,2,3?

Comment: @Liam 31 days in January, 28/29 days in Feb....

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I was looking for another way to achieve that (my solution is heavy enough for a simple thing)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting number of days in a month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832468/getting-number-of-days-in-a-month)

Comment: Cos you know that this is just in the framework [`DateTime.DaysInMonth`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832468/getting-number-of-days-in-a-month)

Comment: @Charanoglu - you literally *type less* to use `nextMonth.Year` in that final call than `DateTime.Now.Year`.

Comment: @Liam yep.. I overlooked it..

Comment: Also, I'm guessing you avoided doing `DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1)` to avoid overflows? Be aware that [AddMonths](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addmonths(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks) already takes care of this: "If the resulting day is not a valid day in the resulting month, the last valid day of the resulting month is used. "

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yep, I had a bit of trouble in the past using it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`AddMonth()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addmonths(v=vs.110).aspx) to ... add a month. Finally, use [`DaysInMonth`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.daysinmonth(v=vs.110).aspx) to get  the number of days in the specified month and year.

```
public static void Main()
{
    // 12 for december as example
    var current = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 12, DateTime.Now.Day);
    var next  = current.AddMonths(1);
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.DaysInMonth(next.Year, next.Month));
}
```

Output

```
31
```

[Try it Online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Zjnskt)

Bonus: you can read the [`AddMonth()` source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,02ff6ea643eb71e8).

Answer (score -2):

```
    public int GetDaysInMonth(DateTime date)
    {
        return DateTime.DaysInMonth(date.Year, date.Month);
    }

    public int GetDaysInNextMonth(DateTime date)
    {
                    //Adding months will automatically sort out the year if need be
        var nextMonth = date.AddMonths(1);
        return DateTime.DaysInMonth(nextMonthDate.Year, nextMonthDate.Month);
    }
```

Comment: What does the ensuring do here? You never use those vars? Why do you want to *Ensure we are dealing with day 1 of month to take care of those 30, 31 days*? The baked in method does all this for you if your trying to throw exceptions

Comment: @Liam good point. AddMonths() doesnt overflow to the next month if next month has less days...had missed that one