# Calculate the number of days per month between two dates in C#

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and I need to calculate the number of days per month between two dates (which chosen with a DateTimePicker)

example:
I have a start date 2 January 2020 and a end date 4 march 2020 then the end result should be

`Jan : 30`
`Feb : 29`
`Mar : 4`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting number of days in a month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832468/getting-number-of-days-in-a-month)

Comment: Did you try anything? this is not a question for this site, nobody will do your homework ;). Show us an effort of trying something and show specific well described issue you have, please

Comment: Moreover, it would be a disservice to you if people would solve your questions before you put in effort because you would not learn.

Comment: 2 January 2020 + Jan : 30 = 32 days ???

Please clarify your question. Do you want the total remaining days or remaining days of each month separately?

Comment: The `DateTime` class does a fine job calculating total number of days between two dates. So all you have to do is iterate the months in the range you're interested in, using `DateTime`'s subtraction to determine the number of days between specific dates of interest. See duplicate for the days in a month, and of course the documentation for dealing with the difference between two dates (which you'll need for the first and last month in your range).

Comment: I disagree, that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832468/getting-number-of-days-in-a-month is a answer to that question, Rubi is asking for different monthes, not only for a single month. Also he wants not only the "full" month, the first and the last months are partial.

Comment: @KargWare, you are right. This question is closable under many other question. And this dupe is not a dupe but a hint to solve the issue. In this state  we still should go in the direction of question deletion.

Comment: Note that the loop on month is the reason it's not a dupe. Your argument is not the reason it's not dupe. Partial month is either  The one you start, `Total Number of Day of Month - Start day`;
 The one you end, `endDate.Day`. A simple substraction is not a a strong enought variation to rules out a dupe. Looping on month needed for the segmentation of the result by month is.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

just use `DateTime` and `TimeSpan`

```cs
using System;
using System.Globalization;

namespace SO
{
    class Program
    {
        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");

            DateTime start = new DateTime(2020, 1, 2); // 2 January 2020
            DateTime end = new DateTime(2020, 3, 4); // 4 March 2020

            if (start.Year == end.Year && start.Month == end.Month) {
                var daysInSingleMonth = end.Day - start.Day;
                Console.WriteLine(start.ToString("MMM", culture) + " (Single Month): " + daysInSingleMonth.ToString("00"));
            } else {
                var daysInFirstMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(start.Year, start.Month) - start.Day;
                Console.WriteLine(start.ToString("MMM", culture) + " (First Month): " + daysInFirstMonth.ToString("00"));

                DateTime current = start.AddMonths(1);
                while (current <= end.AddMonths(-1))
                {
                    var daysInCurrentMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(current.Year, current.Month);
                    Console.WriteLine(current.ToString("MMM", culture) + ": " + daysInCurrentMonth.ToString("00")); 

                    current = current.AddMonths(1);
                }

                var daysInLastMonth = end.Day;
                Console.WriteLine(end.ToString("MMM", culture) + " (Last Month): " + daysInLastMonth.ToString("00"));
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

The output will be.

```
Jan (First Month): 29
Feb: 29
Mar (Last Month): 04
```

You can drop the first and last month and uodate the culture of the formated strig if you needed.

Comment: He's looking for a breakdown by month, not the total number of days.

Comment: _"The question was not 100% clear in the beginning"_ -- "in the beginning"? It's still not clear, having not been edited at all. Here's a suggestion: don't spend your valuable time writing answers to questions that aren't clear. You don't get credit for effort; you get credit for answering a _clear_ question with a _useful_ answer. Which can't happen without a clear question in the first place.

Comment: This would not work if both start and end dates are in the same month of the same year

Comment: @juharr i updated the code (it was a low hanging fruit). I think there are many edge cases are not covered! But the answer should provide an idea and not a 100% solution.