# Date checker program

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I'm creating a little program to give dates for a game. My question is how can I check that the date the program gives me was a real date in the past? For example the lenght of February in a selected year.

My current method is selecting a year and a month from a ComboBox and then it generates 20-60 dates. Then I have a date, for example **02.02.1999**. Then it starts to fill labels with dates with this code:

```
//Fill labels
            int day1 = int.Parse(day);
            for (int i = 1; i < lenght1; i++)
            {
                var labels = Controls.Find("lbl_date_" + i, true);
                var label = (Label)labels[0];
                label.Text = Convert.ToString(day1) + "." + month + "." + year;
                day1++;
                string date_curr = Convert.ToString(label.Text);
```

My goal is to check every date's reality after every cycle and if it is not valid (32nd day of a month etc.) then add 1 to the month. And if I run out of months then add 1 to the year.

Thank you.

Comment: How are you "giving" dates? Typically, if you use the builtin `DateTime` data type you cannot create invalid dates like the 29th of Februrary 2021, or the 31st of April 2020 ...

Comment: Welcome to SO. Usually, with questions, you should write examples of what you tried to do before asking questions. Can you please extend the question with some code?

Comment: If you want to check if Feb has 28 or 29 days ... there are probably a couple douzend questions pertaining to LeapYear detection. Research them. Even better would be to simply use DateTime - Class and add/substract days/months/years - it will automatically produce "existing" dates, i.e. `var someDateApprox12andHalfYearsAgo = DateTime.Now.AddDays(- (12 * 365 + 183 ))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Validate a DateTime in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371987/how-to-validate-a-datetime-in-c)

Comment: Also see [Getting number of days in a month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832468/getting-number-of-days-in-a-month)

Comment: @gunr2171 I tried that but it always said Invalid.

Answer (score 1):

ou can use [DateTime.DaysInMonth()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.daysinmonth?view=net-5.0) method to get the number of days in a given month:

```
int days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(2000, 2); //year: 2000, month: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example showing how to use `DateTime.AddDays()`:

```
// these really come from your ComboBoxes
String day = "30"; // to show that it will roll over into November
String month = "10";
String year = "2021";
int lenght1 = 30;

DateTime dt;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(day + "." + month + "." + year, "d.M.yyyy", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    for (int i = 1; i < lenght1; i++)
    {
        Label label = Controls.Find("lbl_date_" + i, true).FirstOrDefault() as Label;
        if (label != null)
        {
            label.Text = dt.ToString("d.M.yyyy");
        }
        dt = dt.AddDays(1);                   
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Start Date");
}
```